# I want to check if a file having .mp4 extension exist in my folder using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

So the thing is that, I'm storing files of other guys on my server that are mp4 but I need to make sure to delete that later on but sometimes the files remain.

So I want to do something that will detect if any .mp4 file is found in the folder if yes then I can remove it using unlinkSync.

I don't know the filename, that's why I want the system to figure it out

Hope you guys can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `readDir` to read all filenames in a folder. Afterwards you can check the file ending:

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.includes(".mp4"));
  });
});
```

Comment: The mp4 file would be in my main folder that mean no subfolders are there, what should I write after readdir to mention the path

Comment: i would try to use './' as path

Comment: Well it doesn't work, as the file is named as some_file_name. So No .mp4 is being mentioned its hidden

Comment: can you try the absolute path of the folder to see if that works?

Comment: 1 min, I think it worked